# Rails - track user's "actions" with relationship models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm building a math exercise app. I want to store questions that are separated into exercises and each exercise belongs to a different section. Also there are multiple sections for each grade (12 grades in total).

How do i track a user's answer (action)? For instance, when a user browses the app, decides to answer question 7 from exercise 'G1' in section 'G' of Grade 'Pre-K' and provides a correct answer i want to track that and in the future provide him with statistics about his performance.

Currently there isn't a connection between my User model to the questions and i wanted to hear from others as to what would be the most efficient way to tackle this (maybe the models right now are completely wrong)

This is the model diagram for now with has_many, belongs_to relationship (i'll add 'the_question':string and 'answer':string later on to the question model):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all that is missing is a `Answer` model, that is connected to the User.

Optionally, you can define the relations on the "parents" of `Question` too.

```
class Grade < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :sections # optional. i.e. 'users that have answers in this grade'
end

class Section < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :exercises # optional
end

class Exercise < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :questions # optional
end

class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
  has_many :users, :through => :answers # optional
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :answers
end
```

Update: re-reading your description, I think `CorrectAnswer` would be better suitable than `Answer`.

Comment: wouldn't be an overhead to instantiate at least four answers for each question? i thought of storing the answers inside the question somehow

Comment: I would not consider this overhead - I'd say it's the reason why you are using a database. Of course, you could for example put the user IDs in a serialized Array within `Question`, but I don't see the benefit in doing so. Yes, you would save a table and columns within that table, but then you could also just push everything in `Grade`, and forget that you have a database ;)

Comment: btw, could you clarify what you mean by "instantiate at least four answers for each question"? The way my suggestion is supposed to work is this: When a User answers a Question, you check if it is right, and if it is, you create a new Answer (with the User's and Question's IDs as foreign keys).

Comment: there will be questions that i need to show 4 possible answers to and the user will need to pick the correct one. On the other hand there will be questions where the user needs to guess the right answer without options

Comment: Okay, what you could do is: use the `Answer` model to store the possible answers for a question. If a question has only one `Answer`, don't display it. If it has more `Answers`, display them and let the user choose.
Then, create a new model `UserAnswer` and track the User's answers (what you call 'actions' in the title) with that. You could either create a new `UserAnswer` for every answer the User makes and set a `correct` flag. (You can then count all `UserAnwers` where correct == false to get the wrong Answers). Or you use a counter for the incorrect attempts, and re-use the `UserAnswer`